# Android vertical ListView with horizontal scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'd like to create something like infinite calendar day list where rows will be single days and columns will be hours of the day. But because there is more cols then screen is able to contain, I have to be able to scroll whole ListView horizontally (just to view what is beneath the screen) while preserving cell recycling on vertical scroll.

Is this even possible? A was looking for some libraries that allow this but have no success :(

Thanks

Comment: Did you try gridview?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, You can create a `ListView` with a custom `Adapter` that inflates the `HorizontalScrollView`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971534/horizontal-scrollview-in-list-view-item-android) might be the answer to your question.