# Android listview items with horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to use horizontall scrolling items in a vertically scrolling Listview.

Note that the items should scroll horizontally independently of the other items, i.e the whole list should not scroll sideways when dragging sideways.

Comment: Then use a Horizontal Scrollview inside your Listview.

Comment: do you mean UI like cricbuzz?

Comment: anyone post the adapter class code !!

Comment: It was really tough but I used super secret magic google search and on the first,second, third and fourth link were questions all very similar to yours.  Here is the first one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971534/horizontal-scrollview-in-list-view-item-android

Comment: i want to keep around ten widgets(textview,buttons,imageview) in single row of listview.
then values are retrieved from JSON i need to make it as scrollable in horizontal wise to
 see the first row and vertically as to see all the rows of list view.

Answer (score 0):

Take vertical scroll first and in that vertical view take a table row and in that row take Horizontal View. Do these as many time as much you need horizontal view in vertical scroll view......
for easy implementation use TABLE and its Rows instead of vertical view

Answer (score 0):

This should be the code for you list-view-item:

```
<ScrollView
 ....attrs...>
     <!---Your layout---->
</ScrollView>
```

Use this layout as one row of the list view and this should work well.

Also if you already have a code for the adapter class, you wont have to make any changes to it.