# Proper way to implement a two way listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, horizontallistview

I am trying to create a listview, each row of which should be horizontal listview. And I need to add items dynamically. For example, if each item in my horizontal listview can be represented as a class *Item*, then I should be able to create an adapter which displays `ArrayList of Item` and also, I should be able to create an adapter for vertical listview that displays `ArrayList` containing `ArrayList of Item`. Is there any proper, standard and clean method to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [VerticalHorizontalListView](https://github.com/lalit3686/VerticalHorizontalListView) and [twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) libraries that implement such list view
 and of course this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389071/Create-a-Dynamic-Shelfview-in-Android) might be a help, which explains how to implement Dynamic Shelfview in Android.

I found this post on SO :
[Horizontal ScrollView in List View Item Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971534/horizontal-scrollview-in-list-view-item-android) which explains the issue prefectly, you can take a look at that too. I hope this links help you ;)