# Implementing a list that is both vertically & horizontally scrollable

Tags: java, android, user-interface, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a question related to Android app UI implementation. The UI I want to implement is very similar to the **Slideshare** app UI, which I've attached below:

[image]

Apologies for the size of the image. But basically I want to implement a **vertical list**, and each item within the list is another **horizontal list of sub-items**.

My current plan of approach is implementing a vertical `RecyclerView`, and then implementing each item of the list as a horizontal `RecyclerView` **(basically a 2-Dimensional `RecyclerView)`**.

Am I on the right track here? I apologise I cannot provide any code because I am still in the **design phase**. I do not want any code solutions but rather a **guide or small tips** as to how to approach implementing such UI.

Thank you for your time reading this question. Any tips would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You should use RecyclerView or the TwoWayView Library https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can't seem to find a proper API document for the library you suggested, do you know where it is? Or is there none?

Comment: You can look inside the sample app ( https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/tree/master/sample ) and here is a good tutorial on how to implement it  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide ... no official documentation but it's not that hard to implement

Comment: Sweet!! If you post it as an answer I will upvote & accept it as answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TwoWayView library to implement this scenario for bot horizontal and vertical listviews or you can use RecyclerView.

TwoWayView Library: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/

TwoWayView Samples: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/tree/master/sample

You can read a great tutorial about how to implement this on [on this Github page](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [VerticalHorizontalListView](https://github.com/lalit3686/VerticalHorizontalListView) and [twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view)
 and of course this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389071/Create-a-Dynamic-Shelfview-in-Android) might be a help, which explains how to implement Dynamic Shelfview in Android.

I found this answer on SO :
[Horizontal ScrollView in List View Item Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971534/horizontal-scrollview-in-list-view-item-android) which explains the issue prefectly, you can take a look at that too. I hope this links help you ;)

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for your suggestion! Indeed those links seem very resourceful for me :)

Comment: your welcome ;) and of course your question is perfect and helpful.